# In CartoDB, is it possible to associate metadata with dataset columns?

Tags: carto, import, metadata, google-docs

I have some data in google spreadsheets. I've been moving the data to cartodb.com because I want to use CartoDB for mapping. As well as mapping, I want to be able to access the raw data and present it using C3 charts.

Moving away from a generic spreadsheet to an SQL-backed system, I've hit a limitation. I want to be able to show friendly names and tool-tip descriptions for each metric displayed in a chart, but this is data that applies to a whole column.

I can do this in google spreadsheets by reserving specific rows for metadata, but importing this in to cartodb does not work for columns that contain non-string values.

I thought about having a secondary dataset in CartoDB that contains metadata for a primary dataset. Of course, this means making two requests to get all the data for a chart but I assume this would not be prohibitive.

Are there any other workarounds to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm also looking to generate data for CartoDB in a way where each column would have both a technical name and also a description (and in a way that would be usable from CartoDB). Did you find a way to do that?

Comment: The solution I settled on was the second one that I described. I made a second CartoDB table for metadata. The column names were the same as the column names in the data table and all the columns held string values. Once I had this feature, I found myself adding a lot more metadata.